Norm on the space of vector fields
Let $M$ be a finite dimensional manifold. There exists the notion of the norm of a tangent vector field on M? In other words, the space of tangent vector fields is a normed space?
Thank you in advance for the answers.

"Yes." <> Just as there are norms on spaces of vector-valued functions, there are norms on spaces of sections of vector bundles, including vector fields. As for "what norm is useful?", that depends on what exactly you're trying to do (usually, what PDE you're trying to solve). Sobolev norms are a common choice; global analysis may be another useful search term.

Thank you for the answer. Is there a reference for the particular case of the space of section of vector bundles?

That special case is still too big to address. Books on manifolds that discuss Hodge theory or harmonic forms generally develop $L^2$ theory for sections on vector bundles. Books on index theory (as in the Atiyah-Singer index theorem) more generally examine Fredholm differential operators on sections of vector bundles. <> Searching MSE for "global analysis" and/or "Sobolev norm" should point in useful directions if you can't easily say exactly what problem with vector fields you're working on.
